# StratifiedShuffleSplit Wrong Output?

Tags: python, sampling, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to run a StratifiedShuffleSplit based on a categorical variable "Accident_Severity" (Fatal, Serious or slight).

**Initial Distribution:**

> Slight     182994
>
> Serious     40442
>
> Fatal        2973
>
> Name: Accident_Severity, dtype: int64

**When I run this code:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

stratified_splitter = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)    
train_index, test_index = list(stratified_splitter.split(df_full, df_full["Accident_Severity"]))[0] 
df_train = df_full.loc[train_index]    
df_test = df_full.loc    
[test_index]    
print(f"{df_train.shape[0]} train and {df_test.shape[0]} test instances")
```

> 214865 train and 115 test instances

**The result is not proportional as it should. And the test set is not 20% of the 226409 entries**

Final Proportion test:

> Fatal    115
>
> Name: Accident_Severity, dtype: int64

Final Proportion Train:

> Slight     177630
>
> Serious     34856
>
> Fatal        2379
>
> Name: Accident_Severity, dtype: int64

Other colleagues of mine run the same code, and get good outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall and install Anaconda and Run all the code again in my Jupyter notebook. Apparently I got the correct answer and the problem is solved...

Seems that sklearn had something wrong, that I was not able to understand.